# Merge using update insert new rows

Tags: oracle, merge, insert, sql-update, rowid

I have below merge query where i want to update the date and for perfromance issue i am using `ROWID` logic.

But i would like to know does it anyhow inserts new rows ? I just want to update the table `TEST_GRP` and dont want any insertion of new rows.

As i am using `ROWID` logic for the first time i am really not sure whether it insert new rows or just update the table.

```
MERGE INTO TEST_GRP tgt
  USING (SELECT ID,
                ROWID r_id,
                row_number() over (partition by ID ORDER BY DT_DATE) rn
         FROM   TEST_GRP) src
    ON (tgt.rowid = src.r_id AND src.rn = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET DT_DATE = to_date('01.01.2017', ''dd.mm.yyyy'')
  WHERE DT_DATE != to_date('01.01.2016', ''dd.mm.yyyy'')
  and DB_NAME = 'ARD';
```

Comment: I'm curious about why the dates are different in your update vs. the where clause. "Update to 01.01.2017 unless the date is 01.01.2016".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add insert clause to `merge`statement  as stated in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) :

> merge_update_clause ... You can specify this clause by itself or with the
>   merge_insert_clause

And you don't have in it your code so not insert(s) will happen.

merge_insert_clause:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It will update the rows with no problem and does not insert new rows.

At your  UPDATE  statment probalie it can cause you problem the quote at format mask SET DT_DATE = to_date('01.01.2017', ''dd.mm.yyyy'')  DT_DATE != to_date('01.01.2016', ''dd.mm.yyyy'')